# Bigquery UI Now Shows more than 5 rows in Details View

Tags: google-bigquery

There has been an unexpected and unannounced change to the Bigquery UI where selecting to see details of a table shows a preview of more than the five rows that were normally shown before. Now the preview shows what appears to be a complete dump of the table and I'm worried that this will be reflected as a large query come billing time. Moreover, the browser becomes sluggish due to the large amount of data that is downloaded when clicking on the details view.

Since the details view is also the place to see the table info, it is important to me that the previous behavior be restored; I do not want to dump the whole table or even a large chunk of the table in order to see the number of rows in the table and when the table was created or last updated.

So, to summarize the question, are we being charged for a data query when we click on the details view?

Comment: I think this is a great change, because for some reason, unlike this preview, a select statement is unable to display more than one repeated field, and this often rules out `select *` altogether.

Comment: The problem I see with this change is that I deal with truly massive tables. This change is causing the Chrome browser to crash because it cannot handle the load. On these massive tables I cannot click on the details button without crashing the browser.

Comment: You might want to file a report in the issue tracker. I've found the team to be quite responsive there. https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery

Answer (score 3):

Short answer to "*are we being charged for a data query when we click on the details view?*":

**No**.

The web UI display preview feature uses BigQuery's "tabledata.list" API operation that returns certain number of full rows from a table. This is a free operation, and you can use it too.

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/list

In fact, using this method is way faster and cheaper (free) than a "SELECT * LIMIT 10" (in BigQuery's world that SELECT * would be the most expensive without a need operation, since you have a free alternative available).

Comment: Unfortunately, when dealing with truly massive tables this causes the browser to crash.